# String.anotherIndex causes "fatal error: cannot increment endIndex"

Tags: ios, swift

I try to get the distance between a string's startIndex and another index, but get the following error in the first loop iteration. The code actually works with most string, but with some it crashes.

> fatal error: cannot increment endIndex

```
let content = NSMutableAttributedString(string: rawContent, attributes: attrs)

var startIndex = content.string.characters.startIndex

while true {
    let searchRange = startIndex..<rawContent.characters.endIndex
    if let range = rawContent.rangeOfString("\n", range: searchRange) {
        let index = rawContent.characters.startIndex.distanceTo(range.startIndex)
        startIndex = range.startIndex.advancedBy(1)

        rawContent.replaceRange(range, with: "*")
        content.addAttribute(
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
            value: UIColor.redColor(),
            range: NSMakeRange(index, 1))
    }
    else {
        break
    }
}

content.replaceCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(0, content.length), withString: rawContent)
```

`content` is `NSMutableAttributedString` and when the app crashes the variables have the following values:

```
range.startIndex: 164
content.string.characters.startIndex: 0
content.string.characters.endIndex: 437,
content.string.characters.count: 435
```

I don't understand why the error message says about increasing endIndex when I'm trying to calculate the distance from the startIndex and `anotherIndex` is less than the string length.

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from those 4 lines of code?

Comment: The debugger stops in the last line.

Comment: I added all lines to the question. The debugger stops at line let index = ... in the first loop iteration. The code has worked fine so far, but no with some strings it started to crash. The strings contain normal text with some line feeds.

Comment: So basically you are going through this string and removing all `\n` characters and replacing them with `space` characters?  Why not just use `replaceOcurrencesOfString`?

Comment: It's an attributed string and I add attributes to the replaced range. But that's not relevant as the code never goes to that point.

Comment: I changed my code to advance the search index by one in each iteration to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: I changed the code some more. Now the only problem is the NSMakeRange here: content.addAttribute(
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                value: UIColor.redColor(),
                range: NSMakeRange(index, 1))

Comment: It's probably best not to change the code of your question to this extent **after** I posted a complete and carefully considered answer to your original question, including a robust and fully functional solution. As it happens your changes still ignore the main point I'm making about mixing `Range<String.Index>` and `NSRange` metrics. If you copy and paste my solution into a playground and study the code, you'll see that all the APIs are working with `NSRange`, which solves the problem. Also, my code is much safer and will work even if you are replacing substrings of different length.

Comment: if I change the rawContent to NSString my code works because both NSAttributedString and rawContent use the same indexing. Using regexp to find one characters seems like an overkill.

Comment: Soon enough (perhaps with the arrival of Swift 3 this summer) we'll no longer have to work with APIs that mix the new unicode and old code units metrics. So, for a little while longer, we just have to be a bit careful not to mix them in our code. As for the use of `NSRegularExpression`, whilst (ever so) slightly bulky, the proposed code is very performant (especially if you store and reuse the pattern). At any rate, that is just a suggestion, the main point of my answer is to explain the errors you are getting with your current approach.

Comment: I really hope too that Swift3 changes NSAttributedString to Swift AttributedString, which uses the same indexing as Strings. Even better if they get rid of all Objective-C APIs and rewrite all frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

The cause for the error is that you are mixing `Range<String.Index>` and `NSRange` APIs. The first is counting in `Character`s and the second in UTF–16 code units. If you start with:

```
import Cocoa

let content = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "♥️♥️\n")
```

... then your code enters an infinite loop (this refers to @Tapani's original question and I haven't checked if this is still the case after his changes; the central problem remains the same though)! This is because:

```
NSString(string: "♥️♥️\n").length   // 5
"♥️♥️\n".characters.count           // 3
```

... so that you end up replacing (part of) the second heart with a space, leaving the new line in place, which in turn keeps you in the loop.

One way to avoid these problems is to do something along the lines of:

```
let content = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "♥️♥️\n")

let newLinesPattern = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\n", options: [])

let length = (content.string as NSString).length
let fullRange = NSMakeRange(0, length)

let matches = newLinesPattern.matchesInString(content.string, options: [], range: fullRange)

for match in matches.reverse() {
    content.replaceCharactersInRange(match.range, withAttributedString: NSAttributedString(string: " "))
}

content.string // "♥️♥️ "
```

If you copy and paste this into a playground and study the code (e.g. Alt-Click on method names to popup their API), you'll see that this code works exclusively with `NSRange` metrics. It is also much safer as we are looping through the matched ranges in reverse so you can replace them with substrings of different length. Moreover, the use of `NSRegularExpression` makes this a more general solution (plus you can store the patterns and reuse them elsewhere). Finally, replacing with `NSAttributedString`, in addition to `replaceCharactersInRange` being `NSRange` based, also gives you a greater control in the sense that you can either keep the existing attributes (get them from the range you are replacing) or add others...

Comment: But that is not the cause for the crash as you can see from the indexes. My string does not have any characters, which are not in the range 0...255.

Comment: That can't be the fact since your `characters.endIndex` is 437 and `characters.count` is only 435, so one or two "rogue" characters must've sneaked in?

Comment: Also, how do you replace a range or add attributes to a range in NSAttributed string by using Swift String's indexes?

Comment: I would probably enumerate matches using `NSRegularExpression` in reverse and make my changes inside the enumeration block... do you need any help with that? I'd certainly start from scratch, though, since the code as it is now has numerous issues...

Comment: But still you need to be able to map the locatipns from Swift String indexes to NSAttributedString indexes for the attributes.

Comment: In fact there is a `replaceCharactersInRange(_, withAttributedString:)` that takes `NSRange`. I've added one possible approach to my answer. Hope that helps...

Comment: How is it better to replace the LFs in an attributed string with an attributed string instead of a string? Does the NSRange got from NSRegularExpression better take into account the character length with NSRange than the one got from String.rangeOfString? Isn't it basically the same as using NSString's rangeOfString, which returns NSRange?

Comment: I'm just saying that NSAttributedString is based on NSString, which cannot handle different length characters. So if I have an attributed string containing "♥️♥️\n" and add an attribute from 0 to 2 the attribute affects only the first character, right?

Comment: The point is that all the APIs in my proposed solution take and/or return `NSRange` only. I've appended a more explicit paragraph of explanation to my answer. I hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me, but you should be error checking.  And since you are searching the entire `content.string` anyway why add the complexity of setting the search range?

Something like this would be simpler:

```
if let anotherIndex = content.string.rangeOfString("\n")
{
    let index = content.string.startIndex.distanceTo(anotherIndex.startIndex)
}
```

Comment: My code is actually a loop so it has the required checks and that's why it uses the range. But it crashes in the first round of the loop.